# How do I add card details to Stripe customer one piece at a time

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a use case where I am collecting card details from a user one input at a time. Think a process like:

- Collect card number
- Create token
- Create Stripe customer
- Collect card expiration
- Update card created with customer
- Collect CSV
- Update card created with customer

Best I can tell the above flow is not possible.

Additionally if I try to do something like:

- Collect card number
- Create token with fake expiration and csv
- Create Stripe customer...

It looks like it will simply fail the token creation process with card verification errors.

So my question, is there a hidden switch, or some other cheat I can do to make what I'm trying to do work?

Comment: Why are you not just collecting all the card details at the same time?

Comment: Thinking telephone IVR. Can't really collect all those details in one input.

Comment: It appears this is possible with Braintree. 

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/credit-card/create/

I guess I'm going to give it a shot, though that method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it might be possible to use the [Update Card API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_card) to make this work.  Do note that Stripe will attempt to validate the card at each step, which may still cause the failures you're seeing.

Something else to be aware of, since you'll be accepting card details on your server, is that you're going to need to be [PCI compliant](https://stripe.com/docs/security#pci-dss-guidelines).

You might also just want to contact [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) and walk them through your use case, as they may have some other suggestions for you.